# Blocking when updating items from JavaScript JSOM when a SharePoint 2013 workflow is executing?

Tags: 2013, workflow, jsom

I have a fairly complicated script written using the JSOM in Javascript that synchronizes two lists based on user behavior. At one point a user interacts with a SharePoint form that, on closing, triggers a workflow to initiate. After the workflow has been triggered, the script updates a series of fields and should go on its merry way.

However, this is not happening. Instead, whilst I am able to get the item the workflow is operating upon, the moment I call the query to update it, everything hangs until the workflow completes, at which point the JSOM finishes executing asynchronously and does its thing. This would be fine, except I need the changes to be there when the workflow looks for them - that's why it is pausing in the first place.

Does anyone have any ideas off hand as to how to prevent the workflow and script from getting in each other's way?

Comment: Is the workflow being triggered via JSOM as well?

Comment: Also, I edited your question since CSOM usually refers to C#.  Client object model in JavaScript is referred to as JSOM.

Comment: Not yet, although it's one of the mitigations I'm looking into. Can't actually remember how to launch a workflow via JS, although I can think of a couple of ways to early exit unless JS has caused certain conditions to be met.

Comment: Perhaps add a field to the list that you update via JSOM, and then have the workflow wait until field equals the value you set it to.  Otherwise, do it all via JSOM.

Comment: Eventual solution (at least for now) was to roll back to a 2010 workflow which doesn't cause blocking. I tried adding in the extra field, which looked promising but didn't behave as expected, and eventually just decided the fastest resolution would be to use old technology.

Comment: Put that as an answer. If someone else has this issue they could benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two obvious ways to address this:

- A tracking field to say when the workflow is ready
- Rolling back to a SharePoint 2010 workflow which definitely does not do blocking.

The first of these should be the solution. That is, create a field in the list called "WorkflowReady", which JavaScript sets to true once the workflow CAN operate on the field, and the workflow then early exits unless it's true. Assuming blocking operates as expected, this is fine.

However, when I tried it, I found it difficult to confirm that the list item is ALWAYS blocked by either JS or the WorkFlow, leading to the possibility that the worflow starts, check's the value of the field, and yields to JavaScript before finishing. JavaScript could then set the ready field to True BEFORE the workflow completes, the workflow then completes, and the row just sits there, ready to be started but not triggered because the changes were effected during its previous execution. I did not observe this behaviour, but since I couldn't confirm that it would never take place, I didn't go down this route.

The other approach, however, of rolling the workflows back to a 2010 paradigm did the trick. It's far from ideal - sooner or later I guess MS will retire 2010 workflows - but for the immediate problem, it did the job.